# my line 34 code in python has an error and I don't know what is the problem?

Tags: python

```
print("FIRST COME FIRST SERVE SCHEDULLING")
n= int(input("Please enter number of jobs : "))
d = dict()
 
for i in range(n):
    key = "P"+str(i+1)
    a = int(input("Please enter arrival time of jobs"+str(i+1)+": "))
    b = int(input("Please enter burst time of jobs"+str(i+1)+": "))
    l = []
    l.append(a)
    l.append(b)
    d[key] = l
 
d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0])
 
ET = []
for i in range(len(d)):
    # first process
    if(i==0):
        ET.append(d[i][1][1])
 
    # get prevET + newBT
    else:
        ET.append(ET[i-1] + d[i][1][1])
 
TAT = []
for i in range(len(d)):
    TAT.append(ET[i] - d[i][1][0])
 
WT = []
for i in range(len(d)):
    WT.append(TAT[i] - d[i][1][1])
 
 avg_ATT = 0
for i in ATT:
 avg_ATT +=i
avg_ATT = (TAT+n)

avg_WT = 0
for i in WT:
    avg_WT +=i
avg_WT = (avg_WT/n)
 
print("Jobs | Arrival | Burst | Exit | Turn Around | Wait |")
for i in range(n):
      print("   ",d[i][0],"   |   ",d[i][1][0]," |    ",d[i][1][1]," |    ",ET[i],"  |    ",TAT[i],"  |   ",WT[i],"   |  ")
print("Average Turn Around Time: ",avg_ATT)
print("Average Waiting Time: ",avg_WT)
```

PS: the line 34 is the problem
I need some help to run that code can anyone could help me? because I can't figure it I just need to know how the Average Turn Around Time (ATT) will work in this code

Comment: which is line 34 and what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: A quick skim over your code shows you are populating `TAT`, but then later when you compute `avg_ATT` you're trying to iterate over `ATT`, which I don't see defined anywhere. Additionally, the line `avg_ATT = (TAT+n)` looks totally bogus. Don't you mean `avg_ATT = avg_ATT/n`? It would be beneficial for you to read your code _out loud to yourself_ and then explain out loud what every line does. Not what you _think_ it does, but actually read it as if you've never seen it before.

Comment: I actually think that it  is a + I thought it should be the formula of the ATT should write in line 37

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at line 35, because you're trying to iterate `ATT` and it doesn't exist, change it to `TAT` and after that refactor the line 37 otherwise you'll get the error: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

This should work:

```py
avg_ATT = 0
for i in TAT:
    avg_ATT +=i
avg_ATT = (TAT.append(n))
```

Saludos